# Specification of a directed graph

Tags: graph, neo4j

This is a fairly advanced topic related to directed graphs. I am looking into NOSQL technology for a project. In particular, using graph databases. It's a perfect fit in supporting the rich model I want to save relationships for and the problem domain is a graph itself (vertices and edges). Now obviously this made me look at Neo4j and other vendors in this space. Now I believe they def have solved or closed the gap with persisting data in a graph data structure way...which is perfect.

However my requirement goes further where there is a need to understand a specification of a directed graph to create an actual instance of a 'directed graph', such that particular rules and constraints are adhered to when actually creating the graph. The graph database doesn't concern itself with this which is correct and wouldnt want it too (happy that it's agnostic of this). The problem is this leaves it a little open ended as what ensures that the graph complies with your graph rules (ie that certain nodes can have certain relationships or even have relationships to other nodes). What should I be using that will allow me to specify the specification/metadata of the directed graph such that when creating an instance of it at runtime it adheres correctly to it's 
specification.

Any help or suggestions on what is available or what is the standard way to approach this would be appreciated

Comment: Bridging the gap between a graph of nodes and edges as mapped to a relational model with rows and relations is encapsulated in the Enterprise Elements Repository tool...  short answer, you need metadata

Comment: Randy...it's not so much about the mapping to or from a relational store. It's about defining the rules of the graph itself. I want or need this defined. I know it needs to be metadata but of what form. GraphML describes an instance of a graph. Only thing i can think of is describing the specification as a graph itself once and when creating instances it refers to this graph for the rules and constraints.

Comment: Sorry misread your first sentence. Fully agree metadata is needed. But of what type. Is there a standard that can be used.

Comment: yep - i think this is a roll-your-own.  The EE tool i mentioned has a meta-data mapping that allows a di-graph to be constructed from rows and Foreign Key definitions to replace the nodes and edges...  bu tthat is all proprietary and baked in.

Comment: when considering your meta model, think that a given node or edge may exist on one or more graphs.  so it becomes not only the graph specification but also the node and edge contents that together form the output.

Comment: Thanks. At node elements will be store in a relational database. I am leveraging the graph database to store the relationships between nodes. Each node element (object behind the node) will be an instance of a specification object. Certainly these could be used in multiple graphs... But the delegation to it's specification is to ensure the right relationships exist.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at Spring Data Graph, http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/neo4j that is as close as you get in having a powerful mapping layer that can project rules etc, much like JPA or Hibernate.

WDYT?

/peter

Comment: Thanks Peter. I have come across the spring data graph before. I can see it's useful but it's not addressing the prob I have- specification of the graph allowed before actually persisting or creating instances of nodes and edges. Ie. Need a way to denote that node of type n1 can only be associated to node of type n2 with relationship of type x etc. -- would be ideal to have this as a configuration

Comment: mmh, that sounds like you want the "schema" not in the code but in the DB? Sounds like NOSQL are a bit too loose there. However, you can do schema enforcement low-level via the Neo4j Event API, see http://wiki.neo4j.org/content/Event_framework